# Modify file from kubernetes pod

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I want to modify particular config file from kubernetes running pod at runtime.
How can I get pod name at runtime and I can modify the file from running pod and restart it to reflect the changes? I am trying this in python 3.6.

Suppose,
I have two running pods.
In one pod I have config.json file. In that I have

> {
>       "server_url" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080" 
>   }

So I want to replace 127.0.0.1 to other kubernetes service's loadbalancer IP in it.

Comment: You should ideally be using a configMap and load it as volumes on both your Pods where you want to use these configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use downwardAPI to capture the pod name. Develop start up script to get the config file that you want to update. Populate the required values using ' sed' command and then run container process

Comment: Thank you for a response. I did the same. I took the pod name by command and written value in that pod where I want to replace by python script.

Comment: downwardAPI is used to get the meta data of kubernetes pod objects. good to know that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would do this with an initContainer and a templating tool like envsubst or confd or Consul Templates.